# Why is the synthesis of graphene through alkyne trimerization not viable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, catalysis, organometallic-compounds, aromaticity

I have been looking for a rationale on this as massive polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons have been synthesized this way, and with Graphene just being an indefinite expansion of aromatic rings, this has made me rather curious.

Comment: Alkyne trimerization gives substituted benzene, not graphene.

Comment: Yes, but the question is aimed at what prevents using this technique from forming Graphene? Would it no be possible to form a metal alkyne complex bonded to three diacteylene's, and hence, form graphene?

Comment: Trimerization of diacetylene will give you benzene substituted with some acetylene tails. Further trimerization of _that_ will give you some linked system of benzene rings, but not graphene. See, it still has some hydrogens. Graphene has none.

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkyne_trimerisation?wprov=sfla1

Comment: PAHs with limited number of rings has been made from alkyne (e.g. [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/sc/c9sc05404a) and [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Electrochemical-Access-to-Aza%E2%80%90Polycyclic-Aromatic-Kong-Shen/433d275a2922a16ee8cdc371245b1de007a5fc71)). But then making graphene from alkyne is still a long shot.